# Picture caption POI WORD

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am trying insert picture caption using Apache POI, but i dont have any ideas for it. I'm using

```
doc.createParagraph().createRun().addPicture(input, 
Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "picture.png", 
           Units.pixelToEMU(603), Units.pixelToEMU(226));
```

to insert picture and now i would like to add caption for it to be able create Table of Figure. 
I have tried use some styles 
    paragraph.setStyle("Legends");
but it changes only fonts i doesnt work like with "Header1" (I have template). I have looked into styles.xml (in my template where i inserted picture caption using word) and there is

```
-<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Legenda">
<w:name w:val="caption"/>
<w:basedOn w:val="Normalny"/>
<w:next w:val="Normalny"/>
<w:unhideWhenUsed/>
<w:qFormat/>
```

so it looks like i just have to set paragraph w:name w:val as "caption". Am i right? How can i reach it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What one should know about how the [inserting a table of figures](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-table-of-figures-c5ea59c5-487c-4fb2-bd48-e34dd57f0ec1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) works in `Word`:

When we [add captions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-format-or-delete-captions-in-word-82fa82a4-f0f3-438f-a422-34bb5cef9c81?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), then each caption paragraph contains a sequence field `{SEQ figure \* ARABIC}`. The name "figure" is the name of the sequence field. Then, if a table of figures shall be created, `Word` collects all paragraphs which contains such a field to build the table of figures from those.

Until now (`apache poi` version 3.17) does not provide adding captions to figures nor inserting or creating a table of figures, at least as far as I know. So we must do it ourself using the low level [CTSimpleField](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTSimpleField.java).

Example:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSimpleField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

public class CreateWordTableOfFigures {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  InputStream in; 
  CTSimpleField seq;

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Document containing figures");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum...");

  //create paragraph containing figure
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0); //Set spacing after to 0. So caption will follow immediately under the figure.
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  in = new FileInputStream("samplePict1.png");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "samplePict1.png", Units.toEMU(150), Units.toEMU(100));
  in.close();  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph(); //caption for figure
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Picture ");
  seq = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
  seq.setInstr("SEQ figure \\* ARABIC"); //This field is important for creating the table of figures then.
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(": Description of sample picture 1");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum...");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  in = new FileInputStream("samplePict2.png");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "samplePict1.png", Units.toEMU(150), Units.toEMU(100));
  in.close();  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Picture ");
  seq = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
  seq.setInstr("SEQ figure \\* ARABIC");
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(": Description of sample picture 2");


  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Index of figures:");

  //Create table of figures field. Word will updating that field while opening the file.
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  CTSimpleField toc = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
  toc.setInstr("TOC \\c \"figure\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
  toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE); //set dirty to forcing update


  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableOfFigures.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  document.close();

 }

}
```

Note, the inserted field `{TOC \c "figure" \* MERGEFORMAT}`, because it  is set dirty, only forces updating that field while opening the file in `Word`. Creating the whole table of figures using `apache poi` without forcing `Word` doing that will be much more effort.

Comment: thank you. that worked for me. my requirements also include adding the section number in the figure number (ie 2.1 instead of 1). I see that in a sample document with SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1

Comment: Hello, I've taken some of your advice into account, however it seems that after repairing the document, when starting word, the generated table of figures does not allow for " press control + click to follow link " ... which is otherwise available if creating the table of figures manually. Is this happening on your end?

Comment: @EverNight: 1. There are not some advices but a complete working example. 2. There is nothing "repairing the document" but only forcing updating that TOC field. 3. The example works tested in Word 2007, Windows 7 and Word 365, Windows 10. 4. Using this approach Ctrl+Link works only when mouse is over the page number in TOC.

Comment: @AxelRichter 1. I haven't exactly copy-pasted your code ... and was actually wondering if i was missing something. Rest assured, i did so just a few minutes ago and it turns out i'm correct. The table of figures you're generating is incomplete. use MS word to generate a table of figures manually and hover over an etry, and you'll see what i'm talking about.  2. i meant to say " repaginating document " (applies for huge documents since it takes a while in these cases). 3. your tests are conclusively incomplete. 4. false.

Comment: ... right... so i've been checking the document.xml for discrepancies just in case i was missing something... and came across the culprit. Will be posting an " answer " for posterity reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Taking it a step further, I needed to have the caption figure sequence follow my header sequencing. So for header1/header2 I neeed captions to be 1.1.1, 1.1.2, etc. Then adding another header2 they would restart at 1.2.1, 1.2.2. Here is the code for that. It also does not require you to create a table of contents as the answer from Richter (who I thank for pointing me in the right direction with this).

```
public void addCaption(String text) {
    paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setStyle(STYLE_CAPTION);
    paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0); // Set spacing after to 0. So caption will follow immediately under the figure.
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Figure ");
    CTR ctr;
    CTRPr ctrpr;
    CTText ctText;

    CTSimpleField seq = getParagraph().getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
    String figureText1 = " STYLEREF 2 \\s ";
    seq.setInstr(figureText1);
    ctr = seq.addNewR();
    ctrpr = ctr.addNewRPr();
    ctrpr.addNewNoProof();
    ctText = ctr.addNewT();
    ctText.setStringValue("1");

    ctr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewR();
    ctr.addNewNoBreakHyphen();

    seq = getParagraph().getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
    String figureText = " SEQ Figure \\* ARABIC \\s 2 ";
    seq.setInstr(figureText);
    ctr = seq.addNewR();
    ctrpr = ctr.addNewRPr();
    ctrpr.addNewNoProof();
    ctText = ctr.addNewT();
    ctText.setStringValue("1");

    run = paragraph.createRun(); // needed or numbers are at end, ie Figure : some text1.1
    run.setText(": " + text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

right... so in the document xml belonging to a document generated by @AxelRichter 's code, i've manually inserted a table of figures. The resulting xml extracts show that ms word generates this slightly differently...

axel's result:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="009B13D9" w:rsidRDefault="009B13D9">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="TableofFigures"/>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="right" w:leader="dot" w:pos="9350"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Picture 2: Description of sample picture 2</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:tab/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> PAGEREF _Toc521591239 \h </w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>1</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

manual insert result

```
<w:p w:rsidR="009B13D9" w:rsidRDefault="009B13D9">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="TableofFigures"/>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="right" w:leader="dot" w:pos="9350"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:hyperlink w:anchor="_Toc521591266" w:history="1">
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="003A5F7D">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
                <w:noProof/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Picture 2: Description</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="4" w:name="_GoBack"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="4"/>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="003A5F7D">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
                <w:noProof/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve"> of sample picture 2</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:webHidden/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:tab/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:webHidden/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:webHidden/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> PAGEREF _Toc521591266 \h </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:webHidden/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:webHidden/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:webHidden/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>1</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:webHidden/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
        </w:r>
    </w:hyperlink>
</w:p>
```

Having skimmed this thing, it seems that the run should be enveloped in a hyperlink object. ... and there are several subtle differences just to make things interesting.